# Skip email validation in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In Devise Validatable module contains 
`validates_uniqueness_of :email, :allow_blank => true, :if => :email_changed?` 
How to disable this validator?

Comment: did you try removing validation  modules from model

Answer (score 21):

Per [Devise's own documentation on the Validatable module](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Validatable)...

> Validatable creates all needed validations for a user email and password. **It's optional, given you may want to create the validations by yourself.** Automatically validate if the email is present, unique and its format is valid. Also tests presence of password, confirmation and length.

Bolding my emphasis.

You should disable the `Validatable` module and roll your own validations.

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :rememberable,
       :trackable, :timeoutable, :confirmable, :recoverable, :lockable
       # :validatable <-- this one needs to go
```

Review the contents of [`lib/devise/models/validatable.rb`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb) and pull the relevant sections into your own User class. For the current `3.2.x` version line, it should look something like this...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # From Devise module Validatable
  validates_presence_of   :email, if: :email_required?
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, allow_blank: true, if: :email_changed?
  validates_format_of     :email, with: email_regexp, allow_blank: true, if: :email_changed?

  validates_presence_of     :password, if: :password_required?
  validates_confirmation_of :password, if: :password_required?
  validates_length_of       :password, within: password_length, allow_blank: true

  # [ ... ] The rest of your model stuff

  protected

  # From Devise module Validatable
  def password_required?
    !persisted? || !password.nil? || !password_confirmation.nil?
  end

  # From Devise module Validatable
  def email_required?
    true
  end

end
```

Then make whatever changes are necessary.

A real world scenario: I use the [Paranoia gem](https://github.com/radar/paranoia) on a number of projects, which won't work with this module. So I remove it and customize the email uniqueness check to read as...

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, scope: :deleted_at
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your needs you may not need to completely tear out the `Validatable` module.  If you just want to allow empty strings in the email column then you can override the `email_required?` method...

```
class User
...
def email_required?
  false
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that you'll find it very ugly but:

In 1.x devise(we are talking about branch 1.x, right?) there is no options to choose it, so the only way remains is to remove unnecessary validator in class definition after devise directives:

class User extends Mongoid document(no mater, AR is the same here, just place AR Validator class in delete_if method below) and contains devise initializers, so this hack seems to works:

```
User._validators[:email].try{ |validators|
  validators.delete_if{ |validator|
    validator.is_a? Mongoid::Validations::UniquenessValidator
  }
}
```

So, User class definition could be:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :validatable
  _validators[:email].try{ |validators|
    validators.delete_if{ |validator|
      validator.is_a? Mongoid::Validations::UniquenessValidator
    }
  }
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In the model (e.g. User) that you set up devise with:

```
class User
  # devise :database_authenticatable, .... :validatable
  def email_required?
    false
  end

  ## for ActiveRecord < 5.1
  def email_changed?
    false
  end

  ## for ActiveRecord 5.1+
  def will_save_change_to_email?
    false
  end

end
```

Remember to run the migration to drop the index on email:

```
def change
  sql = 'DROP INDEX index_users_on_email ON users'
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
end
```

**Note:** Devise validates email even though `authentication_keys` has been set to something else.

Comment: `def will_save_change_to_email?
    false
  end`
This works in my case with rails 5.1.7

Answer (score 0):

Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24678462/2607291) and then,

> If you already ran device migrations, also make sure to remove that the validation fields like `email` and `encrypted_password` which are set as **can not be null (Added by device)** from the database schema.

Run a migration with something like...

```
change_column :users, :email, :string, null: true
change_column :users, :encrypted_password, :string, null: true
```