# Custom validation on new field in devise model and creating multiple users with same email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, devise

I am new to Rails and I've started building an authentication feature in a sample rails app using "Devise" gem.

I've added a migration to add a new column named *username* in my devise model named **User**.

I've also added some validations regarding the username column that I had created, so my user.rb looks like this:

> ```
> class User < ApplicationRecord
>
> devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
>      :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable
>
>
> validates_presence_of :username
> validates_uniqueness_of :username  
> validates_length_of :username, :minimum => 5, :maximum => 10 
> end
> ```

Now every time during sign up of a new user, I get the validations for username even though it shouldn't.

For example, it tells me username shouldn't be blank even though username is filled.

Username should be minimum 5 characters, even though it is.

What am I doing wrong?
In the console, I can see the username being passed in the params during form submit and also : **Unpermitted parameter :username**.

Secondly, I want to create multiple signups using same email address but different username.

How can I do that?

I'm using ruby 2.4.1 and rails 5.1.4. Thanks.

Comment: There is quite a bit more to this than changing the validations and I don't really recommend it if you are a noob or don't feel confortable digging into the Devise code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do at least four things to get this to work:

#### 1. Setup the proper validations

Since you are not using the authenticable module you should make sure you validate the user properly:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable

  validates_presence_of     :email # optional
  validates_presence_of     :username # required
  validates_uniqueness_of   :username # required    
  validates_presence_of     :password, if: :password_required? # recommended
  validates_confirmation_of :password, if: :password_required? # recommended
  validates_length_of       :password, within: password_length, allow_blank: true # recommended
end
```

#### 2. Configure devise to use :username instead of :email as the authentication column:

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
# ...
config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]
config.reset_password_keys = [ :username  ]
config.confirmation_keys =   [ :username  ]
```

You might want to search `config/initializers/devise.rb` for `:email` to find additional options.

#### 3. Remove the database uniqueness constraint for email:

Generate a new migration and place this in the `change` block:

```
remove_index "users", name: "index_users_on_email"
add_index "users", "email", unique: false
```

If you have not already make sure you have a unique index on `users.username`.

#### 4. Whitelist the params.

Params whitelisting in Devise is a bit more complicated than for your average rails resource due to the amount of configurability.

You need to whitelist the username param both for sign_up and sign_in:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # ...
  before_action :configure_devise_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  # ...

  private
  def configure_devise_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:username], except: [:email])
  end
end
```

The best refence is by [reading the source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/71fc5b351a8e8473733b0ca29d60c06e43a0efe1/lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb#L1) which is very well commented.

Comment: If you want the email to be optional make sure that the db column is nullable.

Comment: You will also need to override the sessions views and change the email input to username. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views

Comment: Hi Max, thank you for a detailed response. As I'm trying this out I have a few questions from your answer. 
1) What is an authenticable module?
2) Where can I find :password_required and :password_length defined?
3) How can I add a migration without adding or removing a column? The change needs to be done in an existion migration file or I have to create a new one? If it's the latter then how can I do the same?

Comment: 1. Devise is built out of several modules. Authenticable is one of them. Each of the arguments is a module:  `devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable ...`.

Comment: 2. seach the devise source code. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=password_length&type=

Comment: 3. In a new migration. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to permit `username` in strong parameters.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
  end
end
```

Please follow https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

- For youre second question :

you need to overwrite devise validation for `Email`
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Use-a-custom-email-validator-with-Devise Will help you,

Follow [Skip email validation in Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210844/skip-email-validation-in-devise)

Comment: I don't know what it's doing, but it certainly works. I'll make sure to read it up. Any idea regarding the second part of my question?